# onclick open child window & submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, forms

so I have a parent and child window 
the parent window have some form in it and I plan to fill the form by value passing from child window that is retrieved from mysql database
but, every time the button to open the children window clicked it trigger 2 event

first , it open the children window 
second , it submit the form in parent window

my question is why the second event happened ? i didnt put any code to submit the form (on parent window) in onclick event yet

this is my code in parent window :

```html
<script language="javascript"> 
  function openWindow() { 
    window.open("blabla.php","_blank","height=600,width=400, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no"); 
  }
</script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>ID USER</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span>
    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id='idk' name='idk' placeholder="Submit ID User" required="required" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><button onClick="javascript:openWindow();">Select</button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer you're question without more information. You need to understand what events are being fired when you're click function is being called to do this pass the event to your function. Then you can see the event object and determine what is causing your the second event to be fired. To do this pass the event object into your function and then you can inspect it.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
  function openWindow(e) {
    console.log(e);
    window.open("blabla.php","_blank","height=600,width=400, 
    status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no"); 
  }
</script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>ID USER</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span>
    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id='idk' name='idk' placeholder="Submit ID User" required="required" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><button onClick="javascript:openWindow(event);">Select</button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish based on the limited information you gave so this is the best I can do to help you. If you are using bootstrap and I see you are using some bootstrap classes. Bootstrap may be submitting your form on the click. Using e.preventDefault() may stop this behavior.

Comment: what other information i can provide to made my question clearer ?